# OpenAPI 3 - How to describe array with allowed key-value attributes in schema?

Tags: api, swagger, openapi

I am trying to create a schema which includes key - value arrays, but the properties are themselves separately defined. For example, lets say I would like to describe a file with following properties:

- id
- fileName
- fileType

where fileType is an object with id and a specific set of acceptable key-value combination, for example

- 0, Word
- 1, Excel
- 2, PDF
- ... etc

I am a bit confused on how to describe this with OpenApi 3 as from the documentation I can't seem to find a way to describe arrays with specific key - value combinations.

Right now I am using an enum like below

```
components:
  schemas:
   fileType:
     type: string
     description: file type
     enum:
      - Word
      - Excel
      - PDF
```

but that is inadequate.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post some examples (e.g. JSON/XML) of how schema instances would look like in actual payload?

Comment: The json would look something like this: {"id":"1","filename":"somefile","filetype":{"1":"Word"}} - what I am trying to do is to enforce specific acceptable key value combinations for filetype so that for example it is clear that {"2":"Word"} is not a valid combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

> Your `fileType` Schema

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    fileType:
      type: object
      description: file type
      properties:
        1:
          type: string
          example: "Word"
        2:
          type: string
          example: "Excel"
        3:
          type: string
          example: "PDF"
```

> Here is your `requestBudy`

```yaml
requestBody:
  description: File
  content:
    '*/*':
      schema:
        properties:
          id:
            type: string
          fileName:
            type: string
          fileType:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/fileType'
```

> Looks like

[image]

Hope this help.